# Display "Free Delivery" if Value = 0 in attribute textfield

Tags: attributes, price, special-price, view

please visit this [link](http://test.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-keychain.html)

search for **Rs 10** using **ctrl + F**

here i am  displaying attribute value [10 ], if value = 0 = > [link](http://test.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-keychain.html)

```
Now value is 10 ,if value = 0, I want to display "Selling Price (Free Delivery )" :

 Means instead of "Selling Price    + Rs 0 Delivery", I want to display "Selling Price ( Free delivery ) "
```

attribute code : "mp_local_shipping_charge"

**Price.phtml**

```
    <span class="price-label"><?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?></span>
 <span class="price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"
<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="lowPrice"<?php endif;?>>
 <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
 <p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price"; ?>
<?php
 echo "+ Rs " . $_product->getData("mp_local_shipping_charge") .  " Delivery ";
?>
```

Comment: please show your attribute value code.

Comment: this is attribute code : "mp_local_shipping_charge"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <span class="price-label"><?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?></span>
  <span class="price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"
  <?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="lowPrice"<?php endif;?>>
  <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
  <?php
      $deliveryPrice = $_product->getData("mp_local_shipping_charge");
      if($deliveryPrice == 0){
                 <p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price (Free Delivery )"; ?>
       }elseif(empty($deliveryPrice)){
                <p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price"; ?>
   <?php  echo "+ Rs 50 Delivery "; ?>     
    <?php }else {?>
    <p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price"; ?>
    <?php
     echo "+ Rs " . $_product->getData("mp_local_shipping_charge") .  " Delivery ";
    ?>                                
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: please check the link

Comment: i have update code plz check

Comment: i am getting error in this line :  <p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price (Free Delivery )"; ?>

Comment: you have forgot to put { after elseif(empty($deliveryPrice)). plz put {.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35678/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-rakesh).